# chars missing in textarea

Tags: javascript, html, css, json, textarea

I have a textarea in a form, the data used ind the field comes from an sql call.
When i load the form not all text is displayed, just the first line.

But when i press space, inter, backspace or another button, all text is displayed

anyone have a solution!

/RMalberg

Comment: do you have some sample code we can look at?

Comment: Is this in a particular browser or all of them?

Comment: it seems to be in the ie browser, haven't tryed it in firefox.

Comment: <tr>
          <td colspan="2">
           <textarea id="noteBody" name="body" rows="5" columns="6"></textarea>
          </td>          
         </tr>

Answer (score 0):

If you have any special char on the text area .then use text as your data type for that particular column in your database .Also set rows and columns and use firefox as a browser.
sometimes it happen for special characters.